# Logarithm integers explanation

Tags: javascript, math, integer, logarithm

I'd like if anyone in the community can explain in detail half the answer to a problem that I found in the web. The problem goes as follows

> Given a N integer, positive , return true if it could be draw as a sum of two or more consecutive integers (10 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) , if not, return false .

And this is the answer I found

```
const consecutiveIntegers = (num) => !Number.isInteger( Math.log2(num));
```

I never came to what Ln or Le meant before, so after research I understand that if a number can be split
 into a Log2 (8 = 3  therefore 8 = 2 * 2 * 2) can't be expressed as asked (no consecutive numbers). But I can't see why the *"The number is not an integer"* (boolean) thing. Shouldn't check the opposite? Number been truly an Integer? Please, do bear in mind that I am trying to understand the answer and no trying to improve it or making it more fancy. 
   Thanks in advance for your time and patience.
   Full credit for the answer to GIDEO.

Comment: Isn't this just asserting that all powers of two cannot be expressed as sequential sums, but all other numbers can?

Comment: See [this math stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94491/a-proof-that-powers-of-two-cannot-be-expressed-as-the-sum-of-multiple-consecutiv)

Comment: Thank you to [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) and [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) for their time and kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a number is called a [polite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polite_number). It is known that the impolite numbers are exactly the powers of 2.

Now, a number `n` is a power of 2 if and only if `log2(n)` is an integer, because of `log2(2^k) = k`.

Comment: But shouldn't be then  ` Number.isInteger `    instead as you are saying now?

Comment: @RobertoGarcia If `log2(n)` is an integer, then `n` is impolite (not the sum of consecutive numbers).

Comment: [Stéphane Laurant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent) Thanks a lot. I have now read the link that you sent me before. Much appreciated!